# Should the sharpe ratio always change with number of assets?

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio, quantitative

I am trying to understand if the Sharpe ratio of a portfolio change if we increase or decrease the number of assets in the portfolio. It would be helpful if you could provide an explanation with references to financial papers.

Comment: Are you asking this in context of some specific model or do you want a completely general answer?

Comment: the sharpe ratio contains portfolio variance, so that component's dynamics with number of assets is discussed here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58314/why-does-the-likelihood-of-corner-solutions-in-portfolios-increase-as-the-number

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I am running a simple LSTM based method for portfolio optimization and I observed similar sharpe ratios while considering the top k stocks (based on return ratio) which seemed a little unusual.

Comment: How do you mean similar and unusual